# How to connect an IP camera to Red5 Server?

Tags: configuration, red5, ip-camera

Does anyone know the configuration from Red5 to connect to an IP camera? Where and how should I do this?

Comment: Connect how? To do what?

Comment: I want to broadcast multiple live IP cameras to flash player using Red5 server

Comment: could you find out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically applications will put video INTO Red5 rather than having Red5 connect to cameras or applications. If you use a language like Flex it's v easy to stream from a web cam to a Red5 app. From there you can have a secondary site to view the stream or saved stream(s).